# Modificar identificador de un grupo LINUX

Tags: linux

deseo cambiar el identificador de un grupo en linux, si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia se lo agradeceria

He usado algunos tutoriales en pdf pero no encuentro respuesta alguna

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar lo que has intentado no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, lo que necesitas es ejecutar el comando `groupmod` con la opcion `-g`, que es el que te permite especificar el nuevo GID.

Un ejemplo seria:

```
sudo groupmod -g 1000 usergroup
```

Donde 1000 es el nuevo GID que queres asignarle a un grupo existente que se llama *usergroup*.Y sudo porque vas a necesitar privilegios de root.

Tene en cuenta que a todos los archivos que tengas fuera de la carpeta `home` le vas a tener que cambiar el GID manualmente. Podes usar `chgrp` y `chown` para cambiarlos.

Comment: Buena respuesta (:)) para una mala pregunta en el sitio (:().